# How bad it is to use a trait instead of inheritance or composition in this case to reuse code?

Tags: php, inheritance, composition, traits

I have a set of services that extend a generic class, which provides some common functionalities between them.

A specific group of these services have one thing in common: they are using a specific resource in an API , so they have a lot of code in common ( to connect to the API and do some GET or POST, aplying the API requirements, basicaly changing the endpoint and the number of parameters to pass).

My question is, is it bad to abstract this code on a trait? and reuse it on whatever services that needs to use that specific piece of code?

Here's some example:

```
trait ApiResource {
    public function retrieve()
    {
        try {
            // apply logic of the resource
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Departments extends Generic {
    use ApiResource;

    public function createCache(Cache $cache)
    {
        $cache->storeDepartments($this->retrieve('departments', 200));
    }
}

class Brands Generic {
    use ApiResource;

    public function createCache(Cache $cache)
    {
        $cache->storeBrands($this->retrieve('brands'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't. Trait is a language assisted copypaste. There's nothing wrong with using it the way you want to.

Comment: This is quite an opinion based question, so I believe it is on the edge of what SO allows. That being said, I rarely find traits a good idea, though exceptions do exist. It looks to me that Object Composition would be the better option here. Some sort of ApiConnector that can be inside a property of your ApiResources and used for the actual communication with the API.

Answer (score 2):

Including it as a trait isn't *inherently* wrong (pun intended), but I think it would make more sense as either an abstract class by which `Generic` extends or even just included in `Generic`.

Presumably this method will apply to all of your `ApiResources`s, but it will *only* ever apply to your `ApiResources` - it won't be used for any other class. So `ApiResource`s should just inherit it normally.

Traits are typically used for one class to inherit methods from multiple sources or multiple unrelated classes to inherit the method - neither of seem to be the case here. I've seen very few cases that traits are good for, and this doesn't seem to be one of them.